# Python: Why are some of Queue.queue's method "unreliable"?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

In the `queue` class from the `Queue` module, there are a few methods, namely, `qsize`, `empty` and `full`, whose documentation claims they are "not reliable".

What exactly is not reliable about them?

I did notice that [on the Python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) site, the following is said about `qsize`:

> Note, qsize() > 0 doesn’t guarantee
>   that a subsequent get() will not
>   block, nor will qsize() < maxsize
>   guarantee that put() will not block.

I personally don't consider that behavior "unreliable". But is this what is meant by "unreliable," or is there some more sinister defect in these methods?

Comment: A link to the specific docs you're referring to would be nice.

Comment: The documentation is useless.  You can't just say "this function is unreliable" in documentation; you need to say exactly what's unreliable about it.

Comment: No doubt http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html .

Comment: @Glenn, please look at http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html : the words "reliable" and "unreliable" do not appear there. The concise, one-line docstrings in the code do use "not reliable" as helpful shorthand, and OF COURSE you go to the MANUAL for complete details: it FAR from **useless** to have short summaries available in the code themselves _in addition__ to the full description in the manual.

Comment: In fact, the current documentation (Google linked me to the old one) has replaced the 2.5 docs which did, quite clearly, say "not reliable" (http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/QueueObjects.html).  Clearly Python folks agrees with me, since they replaced the useless 2.5 text with a real description.  Lose the attitude and do *not* lecture me.

Comment: Current docs: http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/queue.html#queue-objects.

Comment: @Glenn, cool-RR: the current documentation on _Queue.qsize(), empty(), full()_ can certainly be improved to say that the usual caveats on multithreaded behavior apply, and link to the appropriate sections. Here is [how to submit a Documentation Bug](http://docs.python.org/bugs.html). I think it's worth submitting.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, the docs use "unreliable" here  to convey exactly this meaning: for example, in a sense, `qsize` doesn't tell you how many entries there are "right now", a concept that is not necessarily very meaningful in a multithreaded world (except at specific points where synchronization precautions are being taken) -- it tells you how many entries it had "a while ago"... when you act upon that information, even in the very next opcode, the queue might have more entries, or fewer, or none at all maybe, depending on what other threads have been up to in the meantime (if anything;-).

Comment: "Unreliable" suggests any number of problems.  These functions should be completely reliable for certain use cases (eg. detecting if an insert might block, from a queue with a single producer thread).  "Unreliable" is meaningless.

Comment: @Alex Martelli: How can the size reported by qsize not be the size right now? After all, the caller of qsize is holding the mutex, which means that it's the only thread accessing the queue in that moment in time. Or are using the term "right now" as in "right _after_ you finished calling qsize"?

Comment: It's the size "back when" the caller thread was holding the mutex -- which gets released (in a `finally`) as a part of the `return`; that's an earlier instant than the instant in which the calling code in the caller thread RECEIVES the result. The "right now" is the instant in which the result is being bound to a variable or used in any other way whatsoever: by that time, the result being bound or otherwise used could already be out of date.

Comment: @Glenn, see my reply comment to your comment on the question: far from meaningless or useless, the extremely concise summaries in question usefully and meaningfully REMIND the reader of the much more detailed explanations in the manual. e.g. even if `full` is true that does NOT mean you WILL block even in a single producer scenario... it might not be true any more the very next instant (in this extremely specialized case you know no other thread will cause the false->true transition, but you don't know about the true->false transition _even in such a artificial scenario_!-).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which Queue module you're referring to, please can you provide a link?

One possible source of unreliability:  Generally, a queue is read by one thread and written by another.  If you are the only thread accessing a queue, then reliable implementations of qsize(), empty() and full() are possible.  But once other threads get involved, the return value of these methods might be out-of-date by the time you test it.

Comment: Queue.py, part of the standard library.

Comment: There's a Queue.py module in Python's standard library, I added comments to the question to point to its docs. Source is at http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/Queue.py?view=markup .

Comment: Ah ok, I'd foolishly assumed that Queue couldn't be in the stdlib because it doesn't comply with the PEP8 naming conventions.  I guess it's an exception.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

This is one case of unreliability in line with what Alex Martelli suggested:
[JoinableQueue.empty() unreliable? What's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586673/joinablequeue-empty-unreliable-whats-the-alternative)