# JoinableQueue.empty() unreliable? What's the alternative?

Tags: python-3.x, queue

I have a problem in implementing a multi-process piece of code in Python3.3. In particular, I noticed that the Queue.empty() method could return True even if in the previous step we put something in the queue. This seems to happen whit very large objects. This is my simple evidence:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue
>>> queue = JoinableQueue()
>>> large_obj = {key: value for key, value in enumerate(range(40000000))}
>>> queue.put(large_obj)
>>> queue.empty()
True
>>> queue.empty()
False
```

How is this limitation usually solved?

Thanks.

Comment: [`Queue.empty()` is documented as unreliable](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty). What is your actual problem? Describe what you'd like the alternative to do. Do you want `.put()` to block until `.empty()` is `False`? Does `SimpleQueue` work for you?

Comment: I am conditioning the break of some consumer processes according to the fact that a JoinableQueue is empty. When I use my script with very large objects (5Gb) in the queue, the .empty() method break my script.

At the moment, I solved using a Value synchronised object although it seems to inelegant. Any better idea?